# EditTextPreference change value

Tags: android, edittextpreference

I put a value in the EditTextPreference input dialog. If I open the dialog again after touch the EditTextPreference, that first value is showed.

The question is, how can I set another value to be showed when the dialog opens for the second time?.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please, someone could help?

Comment: Another request for help unanswered I'm afraid :-(